# running a single page with dynamic variable as query

Tags: php, html

I am developing a page that sum a summary of report. By default it only shows today. I am using this:

```
include $koneksi
$date ='current_date';
$query1  = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * from daftar where tanggal=subdate($date, 1)");
$result=mysqli_num_rows($query1);
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div class="count blue"><?php echo $result." people(s)"?></div>
```

And it works, the result of query is what I expected.

Now I need to change the value of $date variable with datepicker.

```
<div class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
         <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
         </span>
 </div>
```

I want it so that every time I click on datepicker the variable **$date will change and the page will reload (same page but different query result )** by itself.

Comment: What have you tried? This shouldn't be any more than basic HTML and PHP.

Comment: So you need a client side logic (javascript) that posts the picked date every time it got picked and either triggers a full page reload, or preferably receives the result back and manipulates the already loaded content. So you want to learn about javascript, since you need logic on the client side.

Comment: change `people(s)` into `people`. It won't help, but it won't sting my eyes ;) On a serious note, you need to make a form out of the datepicker and send it somewhere. Then, when you encounter the problem, we will do our best to help you. But you need to show you tries first.

Comment: i have tried 
<?php
         function getdate() {
           
       $current_date=$_get(datepicker);
        
      ?> i am newbie at php my based is on pascal..sorry...
and i think about using session.. because the only parameter is a datepicker...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to displayed in the same page, better you can use Angular. Here, just to show the flow I have used angularJs but the support for angularJs has been stopped so use Angular or reactJs as per your need (search more about it)

Use html to construct a form and using angularJs http.post(), post your form data to php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('input[name="inpDate"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
    });
</script>
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
                  <label>Date</label>
                  <input class="form-control" ng-model="inpDate" id="date" name="inpDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" required="required"/>
    </form>
```

And write a separate angularJs file as below. On submit this will send date to the php file and get the response.

```
$scope.submit = function(){
                     var date1=$scope.inpDate;


               $http.get('http://localhost/report/urfile.php?inpdate='+date1).success(function(shiftdata) {
                $scope.dbValue = shiftdata;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(shiftdata) );
                });
         }
```

after this modify your php will to receive the data and send a response accordingly.

Now the data is URL you can get it in ph like below.
urfile.php

```
$date  = $_GET['inpdate'];
```